# Hold the affirmative

Tags: meaning

What does it mean to hold the affirmative or the negative?
Upon this , Senator Douglas holds the affirmative and Republicans the negative

Answer (score -1):

It's short for holding an opinion regarding the a proposal, or voting correspondingly. Holding the affirmative means you're in favor of the proposal, holding the negative means you're opposed to it.